# height position control in gazebo

Tags: control, ros, gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi guys, i need a height position control for a quadrocopter in gazebo.
Is there any useable plugin to achieve this goal?
I thought of an ultrasonic sensor plugin for gazebo that provides the height information.
Any suggestions are welcome

thanks,greetz

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12573/height-position-control-in-gazebo/) by [hmmm](https://answers.ros.org/users/1556/hmmm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2012-01-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Gazebo has a position_3d plugin that will give you the robot's height. You can use this plugin like so:

```
<gazebo>
  <controller:gazebo_ros_p3d name="p3d_base_controller" plugin="libgazebo_ros_p3d.so">
    <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
    <updateRate>100.0</updateRate>
    <bodyName>base_link</bodyName>
    <topicName>base_pose_ground_truth</topicName>
    <gaussianNoise>0</gaussianNoise>
    <frameName>map</frameName>
    <xyzOffsets>0 0 0</xyzOffsets> 
    <rpyOffsets>0 0 0</rpyOffsets>
    <interface:position name="p3d_base_position"/>
  </controller:gazebo_ros_p3d>
</gazebo>
```

This plugin will publish a `sensor_msgs/Odometry` message that you can extract height from.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-01-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1